# How to get claims in .Net Core 3.1 Web API Controller?

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following configuration in my ASP.NET Core Web API:

```
// Adds Microsoft Identity platform (AAD v2.0) support to protect this Api
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(configuration);

services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .RequireClaim("email")
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```

I have an Angular client application that sends the AuthToken with each request.

Below is my asp.net WEB API controller

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        //Get User Email ID from Claims
        //Get User details from Database
        //Return the User Details
        ...
    }
}
```

In the asp.net WEB API controller, I need to get the Email claim from the AuthToken.

How to get claims in .Net Core 3.1 Web API Controller ? Any best practices to be followed?

**Reference:**
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68817413/how-to-get-user-information-after-login-in-asp-net-core3-1#:~:text=You%20can%20create%20an%20helper%20class%20like%20this%20one%3A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68817413/how-to-get-user-information-after-login-in-asp-net-core3-1#:%7E:text=You%20can%20create%20an%20helper%20class%20like%20this%20one%3A)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 var identity = HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
 var email = identity?.FindFirst("email")?.Value;
 //or
 var email2 = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "email")?.Value
```

Comment: Sorry if this is a noob question but what does the "Type" represent here in an IEnumerable? I see Claims having a list of 19 objects and was not sure what Type means.